# Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade - keyboard problems

Tags: 12.04, keyboard

I made an upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04. It all went smooth, more or less, but at end I have the real problem - my keyboard is not working! I tried both USB/PS2 keyboards, but it's the same story (mouse is working).

So, I can type my password on login screen, and after successful login, I can't use my keyboard at all. What's funny, when I change switch to Guest user keyboard is working. Form that Guest session I can login via "ssh -X" with my user name and keyboard is working perfectly, both in terminal and every program I start. I tried everything I encountered on the web with "keyboard problems in Ubuntu 12.04", but without any solution. I did "upgrade" and "dist-upgrade", I also installed "Gnome" and login into "Gnome-classic" session, but still facing the same problems.

I would be grateful to any help. Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Aleksandar C.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so this is not a real answer, because many things could have gone wrong, but maybe it will help you, and it is too long for a comment. First thing; since your mouse works, you should go to the system settings / keyboard and try to select again your default keyboard. Also, you should attempt to check the keyboard there.

What happened to me a few times was that during upgrade, several of the config files in `~/` did not work or did not work properly. Sometimes it was just too much of a bother to really track down the problem. If that was the case, I did the following (assume that the username is 'foo'):

1. Log in to a text terminal (ctrl-alt-f1)
2. Become root with `sudo -i`
3. Move the old home to a temp directory

   ```
   mv /home/foo /home/foo-backup
   ```
4. Create a new home

   ```
   mkdir /home/foo
   find /etc/skel/ -exec cp {} . \;
   chown -R foo:foo /home/foo
   ```
5. Log in again through the GUI. You now have an empty, vanilla user account. Copy all the files (including configuration files) back to your home directory.